# Transforming a nonlinear system to a new system that has an equilibrium point at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, nonlinear-system

Take a look at the following system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2\\
\dot{x}_2 &= -x_1 + x^3_1 - x_2
\end{align}
$$
which has three equilibrium points (0,0),(1,0), and (-1,0). In the book I'm reading, the author asks to define a new system that has equilibrium point as the origin for (1,0) and (-1,0). The procedure in the book is as follows: 
let $y=x-x_e$ where $x_e$ is an equilibrium point and let's perform the transformation for $x_e = (1,0)$, hence:
$$
\begin{align}
y_1 &= x_1 - (1) = x_1 - 1 \implies \dot{y}_1 = \dot{x}_1 \\
y_2 &= x_2 - (0) = x_2  \implies \dot{y}_2 = \dot{x}_2
\end{align}
$$
The new system is now 
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{y}_1 &= y_2 \\
\dot{y}_2 &= -(y_1+1) + (y_1+1)^3 - y_2
\end{align}
$$
Now we need to show that the new system $\dot{y}=g(y)$ has an equilibrium point at the origin (i.e. $\dot{y}=g(y) \implies 0 = g(y_e)$), we get

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= y_2 \\
0 &= -(y_1+1) + (y_1+1)^3 + y_2
\end{align}
$$
$y_2=0, -(y_1+1) + (y_1+1)^3 = 0 \implies y_1=0,-2$. The new system has two equilibrium points and one of them are not at the origin. How to justify this issue. The actual question in the book states:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ok. When you transform $x\to y$ your old equilibrium $(1,0)$ becomes $(0,0)$ for the $y$-system. You only have to analyze that point for the new system. You cannot avoid by translation having several equilibria.